# Why CopyData utility stopped working after sometime?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am experimenting with idea on how to copy Oracle data from one table to another using Python. I came across cx_oracletool's CopyData utility where i can transfer data between two tables based on key column. I tried in local computer. Problem is CopyData, after running and transferring data to destination table, it stopped working.

Below is the log i got

Copying data...
Source: select * from table1
Destination: table2
3 rows retrieved from source.
0 rows created in destination.
0 rows modified in destination.
3 rows unmodified in destination.

After this i get pop up window saying exe file stopped working.

Comment: Are you running CopyData directly via Python? Or has it been frozen somehow? It sounds like something is going wrong after the work is completed.

Comment: I ran it from command prompt. Like I mentioned in description, after loading the data I get a pop up like copydata stopped running.. I am not sure how to run it from python. I tried adding log file option to it to find the root cause but no error is captured.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on exactly how you ran the program? Provide the exact command that you ran.